# Connection to Azure Cloud Blob Storage fails with invalid certificate

Tags: c#, .net, security, azure

I'm using the Azure Storage Client Library to connect to my azure blob storage and publish some files. Following code is an extract of what I'm using to establish the connection and create a blob container:

```
var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("settingsName"));

client = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

var container = client.GetContainerReference("containerName");
            container.CreateIfNotExists();
```

This works fine on my local machine. However, if I try to run the exact same code on a different server I'm getting following exception:

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Exception exception)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExists(BlobContainerPublicAccessType accessType, BlobRequestOptions requestOptions, OperationContext operationContext)
```

Does anybody have an idea what could be causing this? I've been googling the problem for days now, without any solution.

Comment: Can you share the connection setting for your storage account? Please remove or mask sensitive information like account key.

Comment: my appSettings are as followed: <appSettings>
  <add key="settingsName" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=accountName;AccountKey=accountKey"/>
</appSettings>

It works on my local machine and is exactly the same on the server.

Comment: http://azuresecurity.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20to%20Enable%20SSL%20with%20a%20Self-Signed%20Certificate%20on%20Windows%20Azure You can also try adding the azure certificate as a trusted certificate.

Comment: I understand that something is going wrong in the validation procedure and it appears that the certificate is invalid. But I'm not even sure what certificate it's talking about.

Comment: Are you sure that when you run locally you're not using development storage?

Comment: @user1666620: I understand the steps of creating the certificte and register it in azure. But I didn't see an option to use the certificate in my authentication procedure as posted above.

Comment: is the cert installed locally on the machine suffering the problem as a trusted root certificate ? you don't select which certificate is used in authentication, the machine uses the certs registered as a trusted root cert.

Comment: @j-u-s-t-i-n: yes, I'm 100% sure. I have already published thousands of test files which I see appear in my own azure cloud storage.

Comment: @user1666620: I haven't done anything with certificates on any machine for my small application. I followed a few blogs showing me the steps to connect to the cloud storage and publish files.

Can you explain me what certificate you mean?

Comment: ok, just checking :) What are you running a Cloud Service?  If you remove the offending code do the other parts of the application run?  I ask because typically you don't need to setup any certs to use storage.

Comment: @j-u-s-t-i-n: Well, that's what I thought too. The weird thing is that it works fine on my local machine. The rest of the application runs fine, the issue is in the communication with Azure.

My first thought was a difference in configuration on both servers which is causing the issue.

Do you know if it's possible to use your own certificate to use the cloud storage? And if so, could you pin point how?

Comment: Can you check the date/time on the server where you're running into this problem. Ref: See Martin's comments in this blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpsanders/archive/2009/09/16/troubleshooting-asp-net-the-remote-certificate-is-invalid-according-to-the-validation-procedure.aspx

Comment: @Gaurav Mantri: Thanks for the advice. I'll check it tomorrow, but I'm pretty sure the date is on the server is fine.

Comment: First, figure out if it is a problem: 1) In your app, 2) On your local machine, 3) In Azure.  There are a couple easy ways to do this - run your app on a different machine, or run a known good app (ie. any storage explorer utility) on the same machine.

Comment: @kwill: my app has run succesfully on 2 different machines and only fails on the server. The problem is on the server.

I was planning to install Azure Explorer of Cerebrata to check if I connect with that, but I have to wait until tomorrow.

Comment: @Luc - not sure.  have you tried hitting the storage url in the browser from the server?  I'd be curious to see what the result is.

Comment: @j-u-s-t-i-n: which storage url do you mean? xxx.blob.core.windows.net?

Comment: I just tried to connect to my storage account using an Azure Storage Explorer (https://azurestorageexplorer.codeplex.com/). Works fine on my local machine, but fails with the same exception on the server.

Comment: It looks like there's something weird going on with that server. Is there anything special about that server?Have you tried it on another machine (other than your server)?

Comment: @Gaurav Mantri: I have tried it on 2 different laptops before testing it on the server.. Both worked fine.

Nothing really special.. It's a corporate server which is secured in every way... The port has been opened to be able to connect.

Comment: @Luc shouldn't matter which url you use.  What happens in the browser?

Comment: @j-u-s-t-i-n: I don't know much about these things, but it appears that browsing to the address is completely blocked. I know the IP and port for SSL were opened. This was done succesfully as I don't get the 'Can't connect to remote server etc' message anymore.

Comment: @Luc what message do you get? you can 'unblock' the site.

Comment: @Luc also is Internet Options --> Use TSL 1.0 is checked?

Comment: @j-u-s-t-i-n: thanks for the advice. I have checked the settings and TSL 1.0 and SSL 3.0 are checked.

Comment: @Luc ok. The reason I'm trying to get you to unblock the site and access the storage url from the browser is that I am hoping you will get a more descriptive error message.  From what you have said, the issue exists on the server setup, not in the code.

Comment: @j-u-s-t-i-n: can you explain to me what url I should browse to?

https://accountName.blob.core.windows.net?

Because this even gives an exception on my laptop on which the code runs fine

Comment: @Luc you said you have uploaded test files, so I assume you are using blob storage.  Go to your storage account then click 'Containers'.  Highlight a container and click 'Edit'. Change the access to 'Public' then save.  Then drilldown on the container and copy the url to file - use that to test.

Comment: @j-u-s-t-i-n: Accessing the file like that actually works..
It does give following message:

There is a problem with this website's security certificate.  
   
 The security certificate presented by this website was not issued by a trusted certificate authority.

 But I can Continue to the website to access the file.

Comment: @Luc Try: 1. In Explorer Options, add the URL to your trusted sites. Exit Explorer.

2. Open Explorer again and navigate to the site and click continue to this Web site.

3. Click on the certificate error then select view certificates.

4. Click install certificate and place it in your trusted certificates authority.

5. Try running your code

Comment: @j-u-s-t-i-n: hi, sorry for the late response. I'm not able to find the certificate you're referring too as if I follow your steps, I get a popup to download the file, instead of getting a page on which I can view certificate errors

Answer (score 1):

This thread has been dormant for a while, but I recently ran across this same issue; I thought I would share my results in the hope that others may benefit from this in the future.

We were receiving the same error when attempting to write to an Azure Storage blob from a server, though the same code functioned fine locally and on other servers:

> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

First, we verified that we had the proper certificate authorities installed on the machine. Often, this can be a culprit. However, in our case, we had all of the necessary certificate authorities.

What ended up being the issue was that the **server was not resolving the proper IP address for the storage account** (yourstorageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net).

Locally, try pinging your storage account from the command prompt, like so:

> ping yourstorageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net

You should see that the ping from your local machine is able to resolve an IP address for your blob account (13.88.144.248, etc).

Now try pinging the blob account from your server, where you are getting this exception. If the ping is unable to resolve the IP address, or if it is resolving the wrong IP address (like in my case), you may have found your issue.

If this is the case, adding a simple mapping to the C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file fixed our issue. If you are having the same issue, adding an IP mapping to the file should fix it. The mapping should map the IP from your local ping to the host name of your blob account. Here's an example:

> 13.88.144.248    yourstorageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net

*Note that you will have to run your text editor (Notepad, etc) as Administrator to save the hosts file properly.*

Answer (score 0):

I have just encountered this error message accessing table storage during a unit test where I created a shim for `DateTime.UtcNow`.

This code has been used since at least 2017, so a recent package update must have caused this (using .NET Framework 4.8).