# BlobTrigger: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to setup an `BlobTrigger` within my `FunctionApp` in C#.

I have the following:

```
[FunctionName("BatchRenewalsResponse")]
        public static async Task BatchRenewalsResponse([BlobTrigger("BlobRenewalResponseContainer/{name}", Connection = "AzureRenewalResponseConnectionString")] Stream myBlob, string name, TraceWriter log)
        {
            try
            {
                log.Info($"BatchRenewalsResponse processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");

                var batchNumber = _agreementComponent.GetBatchNumberFromFile(name);

                var response = _agreementComponent.readRenewalXLS(myBlob, name);

                await _agreementComponent.UpdateBatchAndItems(batchNumber, response);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Both `BlobRenewalResponseContainer` and `AzureRenewalResponseConnectionString` are setting located in my `local.settings.json` file.

On startup of my function app, I get the following error message:

> The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel

From my app, I can write to this container, and read from it, but for some reason, I cannot receive a `BlobTrigger`.  Why would I need to have a certificate?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See whether the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40184687/9191057) is helpful. Besides, wrap `BlobRenewalResponseContainer` with `%` to read values from settings or you may still get 404 once this secure channel issue solved.(Connection is automatically resolved without explicit `%`).

Comment: Should "AzureRenewalResponseConnectionString" also be wrapped in % ?

Comment: Don't do that, you will get error as it will search for "%AzureRenewalResponseConnectionString%" in local.setting.json.

Comment: Did you get rid of the error?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I believe it has to do with the Azure not being able to connect/communicate with my PC in my work environment network.  Deploying it to Azure soon and logging, to see if the issue persists when deployed.